# Inserting DropDownList in a TableCell

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, drop-down-menu

```cs
while (reader.Read())
{
    TableRow r = new TableRow();
    TableCell c = new TableCell();

    c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(reader["Name"].ToString()));
    r.Cells.Add(c);
    Table1.Rows.Add(r);

    TableCell c1 = new TableCell();

    c1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(reader["RollID"].ToString()));
    r.Cells.Add(c1);
    Table1.Rows.Add(r);

}
```

i want to add another cell with a dropdownlist for every row.Could any one sort me out with this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do like...

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.ID = "ddl";
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text", "Value")); // add list items
TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
c2.Controls.Add(ddl);
r.Cells.Add(c2);
Table1.Rows.Add(r);
```

Comment: You can get the value back like this.

((DropDownList)c2.Controls[0]).SelectedValue